# 'wanted to fulfill' or 'had wanted to fulfill'

Tags: past-tense

(1) Last month, I was promoted to senior manager. That was one of the dreams I **wanted** to fulfill in my life. (my version)

(2) Last month, I was promoted to senior manager. That was one of the dreams I **had wanted** to fulfill in my life. (my friends' correction)

Is it wrong to use the simple past, "wanted"?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to fulfill- you wanted it to happen and it did

I had wanted to fulfill- you wanted it to happen but then didn't want/care about it anymore and then it happened anyways

Comment: I like to way you explained the difference between the two phrases in question. Thank you very much.